# Combine multiple rows in single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am new to SQL server and i am trying to combine multiple row in single row but i am not able to do it.Can anyone help me out?

Input :

```
Id      |RED    |BUY    |BSW
------------------------------------
1328        NULL    NULL    0.05
1328        NULL    0.06    NULL
1328        0.01    NULL    NULL
1328        0.05    NULL    NULL
1329        NULL    NULL    0.05
1329        NULL    0.05    NULL
1329        0.05    NULL    NULL
```

Output

```
Id         |RED    |BUY    |BSW
------------------------------------
1328        0.01    0.06    0.05
1328        0.05    NUll    NULL
1329        0.05    0.05    0.05
```

Editing data so as to remove `SUM()` conflict.

Comment: Is there just (at most) one row with non-NULL data for each of the columns? Because then you could just `SUM(COALESCE(RED, 0)), SUM(COALESCE(BUY, 0)), ...` and `GROUP BY Id`.

Comment: what logic you have applied & got the following output ? Show your SQL.

Comment: i think given input is not the complete scenario.show the original table data.

Comment: @CompuChip I cannot use `SUM()` over here.

Comment: @KumarHarsh Table contains many columns so i can paste complete table.But every columns for each `Id` contains same value except for `RED`,`BUY`,`BSW`.

Comment: @Flying_Machine why can you not use `SUM`? It works if there is zero or one record for each of the `RED`, `BUY` and `BSW` values. Otherwise please provide a more accurate example or description.

Comment: how about `sum(isnull(red,0)),sum(isnull(buy,0)),sum(isnull(bsw,0))`

Comment: @CompuChip Because in code it checks if value is `0.05` or `0.00` .if  i use `SUM()` then `0.05+0.01` will evaluate to `0.06` which would be wrong.

Comment: @vasin1987 I can not use `SUM()` function.

Comment: @Flying_Machine can you make clearer example. Maybe with all different value so we know what to accomplish. WIth this example it looks like you need SUM() function that's why we come up with that solution

Comment: @vasin1987 Edited data .sorry for confusion.

Comment: @Flying_Machine Please explain your logic here. What make first 3 lines combine into one line and fourth one separate line

Comment: I agree with people here, explain your logic, show us a piece of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT id, 
       Sum(Isnull(red, 0)) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY id 
           ORDER BY id), 
       Sum(Isnull(buy, 0)) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY id 
           ORDER BY id), 
       Sum(Isnull(bsw, 0)) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY id 
           ORDER BY id) 
FROM Table1
GROUP  BY id
```

Comment: your query is giving error.`The isnull function requires 2 argument(s). `

Answer (score 0):

first of all change the field default setting to zero instread of null it will increase the processing speed then try this

```
SELECT id, 
       Sum((red, 0)) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY id 
           ORDER BY id), 
       Sum((buy, 0)) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY id 
           ORDER BY id), 
       Sum((bsw, 0)) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY id 
           ORDER BY id) 
GROUP  BY id
```